# angularjs data binding from jquery dialog

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the jquery dialog with input ng-model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testing">
{{testing}}       // This works
```

But if I declare {{testing}} outside of jquery dialog angular is not binding the data. Why this is happening. How to fix this.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DGFx/1/) currently working

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all of your elements inside a controller.

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

see
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2rNxy/1/)